# failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: loopback attach failed

Tags: docker

I installed docker on ArchLinux and I tried to run the daemon. It failed. When I ran it manually using dockerd I got this explanation.

```
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: loopback attach failed
```

I didn't find many things relevant so far. Only this topic which didn't get the answers I was looking for.
[Docker fails to start after install with "loopback attach failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633212/docker-fails-to-start-after-install-with-loopback-attach-failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15243 was the answer. It was the fact that I updated my kernel without restarting.